# Consume Sharepoint Office 365 web services from Java application

Tags: java, web-services, sharepoint, soap, sharepoint-2013

I am trying to consume Sharepoint Online Office 365 out-of-the-box web services (`Lists.asmx`) from Java application (from the moment `SoapUI 5.3`)

I tried with all 3 types of authentications (`Basic`, `NTLM`, `SPNEGO/Kerberos`) but always get `403 FORBIDDEN` error

If I add `X-FORMS_BASED_AUTH_ACCEPTED=f` header, I get `401 UNAUTHORIZED` or empty return stream depending on authentication type

I've checked [SharePoint 2010: consuming web services from NetSuite - 403 Forbidden error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6753182/sharepoint-2010-consuming-web-services-from-netsuite-403-forbidden-error) and tried to used `Authentication.asmx` before but always get `PasswordNotMatch` error, although I am sure password is correct

I also checked [Authenticating Office 365 SharePoint Online OOTB services](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8093358/authenticating-office-365-sharepoint-online-ootb-services), but no luck

All tests are done in both Windows and Ubuntu environments to avoid [NTLM fails when consuming SharePoint web service from Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8884152/ntlm-fails-when-consuming-sharepoint-web-service-from-java)

The user I use to connect to Sharepoint Online is OK. It has admin rights and I can connect through a browser without any problem.

What do I miss?

Comment: From deleted answers: a good tutorial that helped the OP solve his problem is [available here](http://paulryan.com.au/2014/spo-remote-authentication-rest/).

Answer (score 2):

Only answer can be given with what you tell us is : You have to look what your service wsdl asking for example:
http://www.webservicex.net/globalweather.asmx
service located here have contract(wsdl) like that: 
http://www.webservicex.net/globalweather.asmx?wsdl

Which is don't have any ws-security policy so no authentication required but probably your service wsdl going to have some security requirments and you have to fulfill them.

Comment: Yes, I know that the problem is authentication. Sharepoint online uses Claims Authentication and I have no idea how to use it

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me trying to make a request to SharePoint web services using Postman. I was also receiving the forbidden error while I had tested the credentials another way and they were working fine. It turned out it was another parameter that needed to be set but was showing as forbidden.

Comment: What parameter needed to be set?